# Bootstrap Putting a button outside of navbar ul list

Tags: reactjs, button, navbar, bootstrap-5, nav

I'm trying to have a `button` to the left of the `navbar-toggler-icon` when viewing on smaller screens, but this button seems to be in the center of the navbar. Is there any way to make the space between the `button` and `navbar-toggler-icon` smaller?

Here's my code for the navbar:

```
    <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
        <div className="container">

            <a href="#" class ="navbar-brand"> Logo </a>

            <div className="d-md-none navbar-btn">
                <button className="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown">
                    Register Now
                    <ul className="dropdown-menu">
                        <li>
                            <a href="#" className="dropdown-item">A</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#" className="dropdown-item">B</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#" className="dropdown-item">C</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </button>
            </div>

            <button 
            className="navbar-toggler" 
            data-bs-toggle="collapse" 
            data-bs-target="#nav">
                <span className="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div
                className="collapse navbar-collapse flex-grow-0"
                id="nav"
            >
                <ul className="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="#" className="nav-link">
                        Features
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="#" className="nav-link">
                        About
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item d-inline">
                        <a href="#" className="nav-link">
                        Services
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>

            <div className="d-none d-md-inline">
                <button className="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown">
                    Register
                    <ul className="dropdown-menu">
                        <li>
                            <a href="#" className="dropdown-item">A</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#" className="dropdown-item">B</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#" className="dropdown-item">C</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```